# jquery mobile on Windows phone 7 images not loading

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
```

images address: images/ajax-loader.png

I'm using phonegap and jquery trying to run this simple app i wrote on windows phone 7.
it has no problem running on chrome /ios (images displaying properly) but when i run on win phone 7, images can't be found by jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css, it just displayed as a grey dot on window phone 7 emulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set the images 'Build Action' as 'Content' will solve the issues