# jQuery Mobile icons not showing with Windows Phone emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova, emulation

I am trying to use jQuery Mobile with the Phonegap Windows Phone template.
The problem I am having is that the list item icons will not display.
My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0b2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            // As of Beta 2, jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
            // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page, or when clicking "back"
            // after a form post), hence disabling it.
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });
    </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Home Page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider">Map</li>
                <li><a href="map.html">Map page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Home Page End -->
</body>
</html>
```

If I browse the files in Chrome or Firefox the icons are visible. It only fails in Windows Phone emulator.
Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: Did you try in Destkop IE9? WP7's IE is based on IE9 so there might be the same problem and it would be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer here:
[jquery mobile on Windows phone 7 images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990566/jquery-mobile-on-windows-phone-7-images-not-loading)

Doh!

Just need to set the build action of the icons to Content